# Using wiredep to inject bower SCSS dependencies

Tags: sass, gulp, bootstrap-sass, wiredep

I've been using wiredep with gulp to add dependencies to my index.html. I intend to keep my custom js separate from my dependency js (the same goes for scss). I will use 'gulp-useref' to concatenate these files to app.css/js and libs.css/js.

I have successfully added my custom JS and bower JS files, and have concatenated all my custom SCSS, compiled it and imported it.

I am having an issue around using Wiredep to import SCSS files from bower, for example in bootstrap-scss the main dependency file is "assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss".

I have tried the following but it isn't injecting the dependency:

```html
<!-- bower:scss -->
<!-- endbower -->
```

Anyone have any ideas on the correct process for achieving the desired result?

Answer (score 2):

SCSS files must be injected into the libs.scss file, not the HTML -  using:

```
// bower:scss
// endbower
```